# I want to enable Kafka errorhandling by annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I tried to enable spring-kafka errorhandling by annotation.

So I created a bean `kafkaListenerErrorHandler`.

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    KafkaListenerErrorHandler kafkaListenerErrorHandler = (message, exception) -> {
        MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
        ConsumerRecord<String, EventV1> consumerRecord = new ConsumerRecord<>(
                headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC, String.class),
                headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID, Integer.class),
                headers.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, Long.class),
                headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, String.class),
                (EventV1) message.getPayload());
        errorHandler.handle(exception, Collections.singletonList(consumerRecord), headers.get(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER, Consumer.class), messageListenerContainer);
        return null;
    };

    return kafkaListenerErrorHandler;
}
```

and wired it with the `KafkaListener` by

```
@Autowired(required = false)
MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer;

@Autowired
private UserBO userBO;

@Bean
ErrorHandler errorHandler(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
    return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(kafkaTemplate), new FixedBackOff(0, 2));
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.listener.topics}'.split(',')}", errorHandler = "kafkaListenerErrorHandler")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, EventV1> message) {

    log.info("Received Messasge: {}", message);
    try {
        EventV1 value = message.value();
        userBO.getUserById(value.getCustomerId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ListenerExecutionFailedException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Even if it seems to work, the code seems ugly. The `kafkaListenerErrorHandler` constructs a new ConsumerRecord to forward it to the ErrorHandler and the "messageListenerContainer" is null, because I didn't find out how to get it into my context.

There should or must be a more elegant way to connect the ErrorHandler with the KafkaListenerErrorHandler

I also added a deserialization error handler to my setup.

`spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the listener error handler; spring boot will automatically wire the `errorHandler` into the listener container and it will be called from there if the listener throws an exception.

Also what you are doing is wrong since the error handler will only seek the current record and there are likely to be more records fetched in the last poll.

`KafkaListenerErrorHandler`s are higher up in the stack and are used for more advanced error handling.

For example, in a request/reply scenario, (the listener method returns a reply value), a listener error handler can return an error reply to the sender of the request message.

**EDIT**

Exceptions can be classified as "not retryable".

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek-to-current).

> Starting with version 2.3, the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` considers certain exceptions to be fatal, and retries are skipped for such exceptions; the recoverer is invoked on the first failure.
>   The exceptions that are considered fatal, by default, are:

- `DeserializationException`
- `MessageConversionException`
- `MethodArgumentResolutionException`
- `NoSuchMethodException`
- `ClassCastException`

> since these exceptions are unlikely to be resolved on a retried delivery.
>
> You can add more exception types to the not-retryable category, or completely replace the `BinaryExceptionClassifier` with your own configured classifier.
>   See the Javadocs for `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` for more information, as well as those for the `spring-retry` `BinaryExceptionClassifier`.
>
> Here is an example that adds `IllegalArgumentException` to the not-retryable exceptions:

```java
@Bean
public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler errorHandler(BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> recoverer) {
    SeekToCurrentErrorHandler handler = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(recoverer);
    handler.addNotRetryableException(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    return handler;
}
```

Comment: So i can just remove that wiring code, great.
But how can i fix that errorHandler seeking issue, you mentioned?

Comment: By the way i also added a deserialization error handler. Like
    spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
 
 
 
 spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*

Comment: The "seeking problem" is only because you are incorrectly calling the error handler from the listener error handler. Remove the listener error handler and it will all work correctly. The `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` is a mechanism whereby deserialization exceptions can be sent to the error handler; without it, Spring doesn't get enough information about the problem.

Comment: Hi,
an additional question.
Is it possible to bypass the retry and forward particular exception direct to the DLT?